# Is there a CFG that supports division, exponentiation, and functions like sine?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I want to write a java CFG parser for expressions that accounts for the following:

1. Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division and Exponentiation with symbols +, -, *, /, and ^
2. Pairs of parentheses () and absolute value ||
3. Sine (I will know how to work with other functions if I work with a sine)
4. Variables are given by single letters that do not form the keyword sin
5. Numbers which are integers

I already made AdditionExpression, SubtractionExpression, MultiplicationExpression, DivisionExpression, ExponentiationExpression, and CompositionExpression classes which implement an Expression interface and I know how to code the parser once I have the production rules but I don't know how to come up with the production rules in a way that is semantically unambiguous (there is only one mathematically correct way to read the expression and that expression is consistent with the usual order of operations but it is ok that x+y+z can be interpreted as either (x+y)+z or x+(y+z)) and efficient (doesn't require too much computing power compared to a less efficient set of production rules)

In summary, I don't have a question about the java code but about writing the production rules for my problem.

I found that this is a production rule for multiplication, addition, and parentheses

E -> E+M|M

M -> M*X|X

X -> (E)|L

L -> [a-z]|[0-9]+

This is my guess based on the fact that it seems that the order of the production from top to bottom is from last in the order of operations to first in the order of operations but I don't know if this is actually true.

E -> E+M|M

M -> M-X|X

X -> X*Y|Y

Y -> Y/Z|Z

Z -> Z^W|W

V -> (E)|L

L -> |E| | A (here I am using the | for absolute value)

A -> [a-z]|[0-9]+

I don't know if this is as efficient as it could be or if it even works and I'm not sure how to account for sequences of characters that represent functions like sin. I know that I would look for occurrences of sin using indexOf similar to addition and the + sign but I don't know where in the set of production rules to put it.

**EDIT:** It would also be great that if the grammar could also deal with things like 2x or (x+1)(x+2) where the * symbol is omitted

Comment: There are parser generators like JavaCC and ANTLR.

Comment: As `+ -` and `* /` have the same precedence, like in a/b*c = (a/b)*c, introduce additive operator and multiplicative operator. as non-terminal.

Comment: That makes sense. I got it to work except for omitting the * operator but I think I've got that too. It looks like JavaCC did exactly what I wanted but I've already written the code.